# Create a new dataframe that list of keywords with sum of their respective value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So here is the issue :
I have a dataframe that contains a list of keywords.
I have a bigger dataframe with commentaries that contain those keywords and values.

My goal is to look into the bigger dataframe with the keywords of the first dataframe and sum the respective value in each line creating a new dataframe.

Here is an example I created:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1':['1d1 a','b xa2','mx1 b','b x12','c xas','d 123','xas c','a vx3','z mp','c xg'] , 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

keywords = {'col1':['a','b','c']}
letters = keywords['col1']

for x in letters:

    a1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains(x,na=False)] 
    a2 = a1['col2'].sum()
    a3 = {'letter':[x],'sum':[a2]}
    a = pd.DataFrame(data=a3)
```

But the results are a dataframe only containing the keywords

letter   sum
0   c        22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1':['1d1 a','b xa2','mx1 b','b x12','c xas','d 123','xas c','a vx3','z mp','c xg'] , 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

keywords = {'col1':['a','b','c']}
letters = keywords['col1']
a3 = []
for x in letters:
    a1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains(x,na=False)] 
    a2 = a1['col2'].sum()
    a3.append({'letter':x,'sum':a2})
a = pd.DataFrame(data=a3)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
  letter  sum
0      a   23
1      b    9
2      c   22
```

Answer (score 1):

In your solution need append each dictioanry to list and then pass to `DataFrame` out of loop:

```
out = []
for x in letters:
    a1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains(x,na=False)] 
    a2 = a1['col2'].sum()
    a3 = {'letter':x,'sum':a2}
    out.append(a3)

a = pd.DataFrame(data=out)
```

Another solution with loop comprehension and same output:

```
out = [{'letter':x, 'sum':df.loc[df['col1'].str.contains(x,na=False), 'col2'].sum()} 
         for x in letters]
a = pd.DataFrame(data=out)
print (a)
  letter  sum
0      a   23
1      b    9
2      c   22
```

Comment: thats it! thank you very much for your help kind stranger!